# Conflict serializibility

Tags: concurrency, database-theory

So, the task is to prove the following:

> If S is a schedule containing at most one write action, then S is conflict-serializable.

The answer is yes, but I disagree, because the following schedule contains at most one write action, and is not conflict-serializable:

> R1(A), R2(A), W2(A), R1(A).

Am I completely wrong? Or is the answer wrong?

Comment: The statement is true if in a transaction there is only one read on a datum (no repeated reads). And this a reasonable assumption when discussing schedules (and also in practice).

Comment: But let´s say repeated reads are allowed. If we just look at this in theory and not practical, does the assumption hold?

Comment: In this case I think the assumption does not hold.

Comment: So the given schedule is not allowed basically?

Comment: I think the statement to prove should be interpreted in this way (no duplicate operations on data). However, I looked in several well-known books on databases and didn't find an explicit prohibition of replication of operations on the same data in the definition of a schedule. So, it is not clear to me if this is just a case of underspecification or something else.

Comment: I did also search a lot for the answer, but cannot see if it is not allowed with duplicates. Anyways, I have asked my teacher, and I will provide you the answer if I get one! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In transaction theory, it's usually assumed that a transaction reads or writes a same data item at most once. So your schedule is not valid since the transaction 1 reads A twice.

Unfortunately, text books do not always make it very easy to find. Here are some quotes I can find.

Philip A. Bernstein, Vassos Hadzilacos, Nathan Goodman
"Concurrency Control and Recovery in Database Systems" P.21 Section 2.1

> To keep this notation unambiguous, we assume that no transaction reads or writes a data item more than once.

Gerhard Weikum, Gottfried Vossen
"Transactional Information Systems: Theory, Algorithms, and the Practice of Concurrency Control and Recovery" P.47 Section 2.3

> To exclude redundancies of this kind, we henceforth make the following assumptions: 
>   in each transaction each data item is read or written at most once

Answer (score 0):

The resulting precedence graph for your example will contain a cycle due to $R1(A) W2(A) R1(A)$. Hence its not conflict serializable. Since one example is sufficient to disprove the statement, therefore I agree with you. The answer might be wrong.

Comment: @Renzo Not allowing duplicate reads combined with the condition of having at most one write operation essentially leaves us with the choice of operations like $R1(A) W2(A)$ or $R2(A) W1(A)$. This becomes too simple to be seen as serializable. Whats's to prove here then? or have I misunderstood something?